# Merging tags 'circuit-theory' and 'circuit-analysis'

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [circuit-analysis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit-analysis) has around 5000+ questions. And [circuit-theory](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit-theory) has around 100 questions which look very similar to the questions under [circuit-analysis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit-analysis). Can we merge these tags to [circuit-analysis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit-analysis) tag?

**Note:** These are the similar tags existing on the site: [circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuit) (1 question), and [circuits](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuits) (161 questions)

Answer (score 1):

I also think they are different an should not be merged. Maybe we should double check the use and consider retagging questions to the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret those tags slightly differently, where `circuit-theory` covers all manner of tools and laws to understand how circuits work. Questions about how to apply KCL or Thevenin on sample circuits would appear using this tag.

`circuit-analysis` on the other hand (to me) is more suited for tagging questions that have a *specific* circuit (real-world), where perhaps the appropriate analytical tool(s) is/are not known by the OP.